# PHP array_diff() convert to string

Tags: php

Hi I'm trying to remove the results of one array from another and store the result as a comma seperated list of strings.

This is the code I have so far:

```
function bpdev_include_users(){
 //list of users to exclude

global $wpdb;
$frndsof = array();
$frnds = array();
$result = array();
$friendsid = array();

$currentuser_id = get_current_user_id();
echo $currentuser_id;
?><br />
<?php

$sql= "SELECT friend_user_id  FROM wp_bp_friends WHERE initiator_user_id='".$currentuser_id."' AND is_confirmed = 1";
$friendsid = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
print_r($friendsid);
?><br />
<?php
$myexcluded_users=array();
foreach($friendsid as $oneitem){
    $myexcluded_users[]=$oneitem->friend_user_id;
} 
$excluded_user =implode(", ",$myexcluded_users);
echo $excluded_user;
?><br />
<?php

foreach ( $friendsid as $row )
{
$sql1= "SELECT friend_user_id  FROM wp_bp_friends WHERE initiator_user_id='".$row->friend_user_id."' AND is_confirmed = 1";
$ffid = $wpdb->get_results($sql1);
print_r($ffid);
?><br />
<?php
}
```

More code (sorry weird formatting issues...)

```
$my_users = array();foreach($ffid as $oneitem){
    $my_users[]=$oneitem->friend_user_id;
} 
$my_user =implode(", ",$my_users);
echo $my_user;


$sql2= "SELECT user_id FROM wp_bp_xprofile_data";
$users = $wpdb->get_results($sql2);



$result = array_merge($friendsid, $ffid);


//$excluded_user = array_diff($users , $result); //comma separated ids of users whom you want to exclude

}


bpdev_include_users();
```

What I'm trying to end up with is

```
$excluded_user = 1, 2, 3, 4;
```

Currently I'm getting an error at the array_diff stage: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

This is the output from the above code

1

Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [friend_user_id] => 54 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [friend_user_id] => 48 ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [friend_user_id] => 61 ) )

54, 48, 61

Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [friend_user_id] => 62 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [friend_user_id] => 51 ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [friend_user_id] => 60 ) [3] => stdClass Object ( [friend_user_id] => 65 ) [4] => stdClass Object ( [friend_user_id] => 56 ) )
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [friend_user_id] => 43 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [friend_user_id] => 50 ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [friend_user_id] => 64 ) [3] => stdClass Object ( [friend_user_id] => 45 ) [4] => stdClass Object ( [friend_user_id] => 44 ) )
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [friend_user_id] => 57 ) )

57

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Are you sure it should be $ffid = $wpdb->get_results($sql1) and not $ffid .= $wpdb->get_results($sql1) ? (concatenation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to access the stdclass in the array.

```php
$myexcluded_users = [];

foreach ($excluded_user as $oneitem) {
    $myexcluded_users[] = $oneitem->friend_user_id;
} 

$excluded_user = implode(', ', $myexcluded_users);
```

---

Edit:

So this line,

```php
$excluded_user = array_diff($users , $result); // comma separated ids of users whom you want to exclude
```

both `$users` and `$result` are the arrays that have the `stdClass` inside them?

How about this?

```php
$usersarray = [];
    
foreach ($users as $oneitem) {
    $usersarray[] = $oneitem->friend_user_id;
} 

$resultarray = [];
    
foreach ($result as $oneitem) {
    $resultarray[] = $oneitem->friend_user_id;
} 

$excluded_user = array_diff($usersarray, $resultarray);
$excluded_user = implode(', ', $excluded_user);
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion - I think it has definitely put me in the right direction. I've edited the original question now to reflect how I've tried to implement this

Comment: I'm confused by your edit.  The snippet I posted just needed to be added at the bottom after `$excluded_user = array_diff($users , $result); //comma separated ids of     users whom you want to exclude
`  It takes the current result that you had in $excluded_user and formats it to the output that you wanted.

Comment: I cant include $excluded_user = array_diff($users , $result); //comma separated ids of users whom you want to exclude - that's what gives me the Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

Comment: thanks for your help and patience - I've accepted this as the answer. There is still one part which is confusing me though. When I use print_r($ffid); it outputs 3 arrays and using implode and echo outputs the id 57, ignoring the id's in the other arrays (you can see this output in my question). This messes up the result in $excluded_user... Have you any idea why it might put the $ffid into 3 arrays?

Comment: just figured it out $friendsid has 3 results,hence the 3 arrays.... Just need to work out how to store them all in $results now!

Comment: Use the same foreach for for $friendsid `$resultarray =array();
foreach($result as $oneitem){
    $resultarray[]=$oneitem->friend_user_id;
} ` ..  You want to get those ids out of the nested stdclass and into a basic array.  Then you can merge and diff it how you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `implode()` for this purpose. This function will separate the array using the string you specified. Check out this [reference](http://php.net/implode) Use the code below

```
echo implode(", ", array("HELLO", "WORLD", "lan", "Butler")); // Will Seprate the array
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: that also gives the error Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string